# Cannot mount USB, Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: usb, 10.04

Using my Vodafone WebBook running Ubuntu 10.04, it suddenly stopped showing USB when inserted. I tried using another USB device, even a mouse. This also didn't work. Charging my phone via USB also doesn't work any more. If I press *Ctrl + Alt + F12* then insert a USB device it says "cannot enumerate USB hub/port 1". What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 10.04 hasn't continued support. I recommend to you install 12.04lts or better 14.04lts 
1.- Inser't USB when all of system is loaded.
2.- See at kernel log or system log if there's new hardware: 
(all with root privileges) 
my kern.log :   `tail -20 /var/log/kern.log`  - to see last 20 lines

```
Mar  9 08:52:49 gilito-MS-AF1511 kernel: [  188.426947] nspr-2: sending ioctl 5393 to a partition!
Mar  9 08:52:49 gilito-MS-AF1511 kernel: [  188.426964] nspr-2: sending ioctl 5393 to a partition!
Mar  9 09:01:59 gilito-MS-AF1511 kernel: [  738.144354] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
Mar  9 09:01:59 gilito-MS-AF1511 kernel: [  738.274613] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=13fe, idProduct=1d00
Mar  9 09:01:59 gilito-MS-AF1511 kernel: [  738.274617] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Mar  9 09:01:59 gilito-MS-AF1511 kernel: [  738.274619] usb 3-1: Product: DataTraveler 2.0
Mar  9 09:01:59 gilito-MS-AF1511 kernel: [  738.274620] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Kingston
Mar  9 09:01:59 gilito-MS-AF1511 kernel: [  738.274622] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 5B740689B724
Mar  9 09:01:59 gilito-MS-AF1511 kernel: [  738.274948] usb-storage 3-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Mar  9 09:01:59 gilito-MS-AF1511 kernel: [  738.275048] scsi8 : usb-storage 3-1:1.0
Mar  9 09:02:00 gilito-MS-AF1511 kernel: [  739.273732] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Kingston DataTraveler 2.0 PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
Mar  9 09:02:00 gilito-MS-AF1511 kernel: [  739.274360] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg5 type 0
Mar  9 09:02:00 gilito-MS-AF1511 kernel: [  739.457335] sd 8:0:0:0: [sde] 2015232 512-byte logical blocks: (1.03 GB/984 MiB)
Mar  9 09:02:00 gilito-MS-AF1511 kernel: [  739.457477] sd 8:0:0:0: [sde] Write Protect is off
Mar  9 09:02:00 gilito-MS-AF1511 kernel: [  739.457482] sd 8:0:0:0: [sde] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
Mar  9 09:02:00 gilito-MS-AF1511 kernel: [  739.457620] sd 8:0:0:0: [sde] No Caching mode page found
Mar  9 09:02:00 gilito-MS-AF1511 kernel: [  739.457623] sd 8:0:0:0: [sde] Assuming drive cache: write through
Mar  9 09:02:00 gilito-MS-AF1511 kernel: [  739.459288]  sde: sde1
Mar  9 09:02:00 gilito-MS-AF1511 kernel: [  739.460031] sd 8:0:0:0: [sde] Attached SCSI removable disk
Mar  9 09:02:02 gilito-MS-AF1511 kernel: [  741.866529] FAT-fs (sde1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
```

3.- Mount your new **partition** in my case /dev/sde1 : `mount -t vfat /dev/sde1 
/mnt/`

If you don't see any new USB device inserted in your log, there's a problem with USB device or USB drivers or USB port PC.